# How to get the thread information for a specific webapplication in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I am working in a web application. I need to display all the thread associated with the Web-Application and each threads information. I have tried the following

```
for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    // get the required thread information
    // is alive
    // is daemon
    // get name 
    // thread.getThreadGroup().getName()
    // etc
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it is giving all the thread information which are deployed in the server(Tomcat). But I  need the threads that are associated to this web application only. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Threads are not associated with a webapp. Threads are used to process incoming requests of all webapps loaded by the Tomcat instance. They are shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze the thread behavior then you can use **jconsole** or **jvisualvm** exe file that is located in the bin directory of the java installation directory .It works on the basis of process id just find the process id of the web application.

Comment: Is there any api that can be integrated with web application and display the process and thread similar to jconsole or any profiling tool?

Comment: jconsole and jvisualvm are profiling tool only , which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Can we integrate those in web application. Which can show the thread details in jsp or some html format? Eclipse

Comment: yes you can download jrocket for integrated environment @N3WOS  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/jrockit/intro/eclipse.html

Comment: link from eclipse site http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/january/article2.php